# Holomorphic function on annulus around $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $f(i/n)=i/2n$ and $f(-\frac{i}{n})=-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$?($\mathbb{D}$=unit disc)
My first idea was to use the identity principle and show that this only holds for $f\equiv0$ but since $0$ is removed from the domain I think I can't use it right? Would it be a valid argument to say we continue the function to $0$ with $f(0)=0$, then it would be equivalent to the zero function and then say that by removing the $0$ from the domain we don't change anything?

Comment: How does the zero function have these values?!

Comment: Why would you even consider $f\equiv 0$? It's already given that $f$ takes non-zero values.

Comment: If $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is an open set, $A \subseteq \Omega$ has no limit point in $\Omega$ and $w: A \to \mathbb{C}$ is any function, then the interpolation problem "$f \in H(\Omega)$, $f(a)=w(a)$ $(a \in A)$" is solvable, see Rudin: Real and Compley Analysis, Theorem 15.15.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron You are right! I tried it like this: consider the function $g(z)=\frac{z}{2}$. Then by identity principle $g(z)=f(z),\, \forall z\in \mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$. Then the second equation for $f$ cannot hold. But it seems like it still doesn‘t work, since $\lim_{n\to \inf} \frac{i}{n} =0$ is not in the domain..

Comment: @MilesDefis That's right. You cannot do it like that since $0$ is not in the set. Also the command for $\infty$ is \infty . $\inf$ stands for infimum in analysis.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Any hint how to work on this?

Comment: @MilesDefis Gerd already told you where to look.